# How to Restore completely deleted Virtualbox Linux.VDI on Linux ? Already restored it but to DD image, don't have a backup

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualbox, files, vdi

so I accidentally deleted the Linux.VDI from my Virtualbox it's a Linux/Ubuntu64 VDI,

I had a success by restoring the file but only to a Linux.dd , I have tried different things to get it back working on my VBox but without any success

Yes I did convert too the dd back to vdi file and tried to add it to Virtualbox but it always shows Error, the Error is usaully i can't add the VDI to Vbox instance or when i boot it up it shows No bootable medium found...

Does anyone know how to correctly do it on Linux, can i run the dd file in Virtualbox or how to correctly do it if i converted the dd back to vdi ?

By the way the host is linux and vbox vdi is also linux

I want a way to access the files on this VDI or DD image , how can I do it ?

Maybe there is a way to access Files that was on this Disk Image, maybe I don't even have to convert dd back to vbox image and I can simply do it by using some programming tech